# Android BOOT COMPLETED firing frequently

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on an application in android that starts a service on BOOT_COMPLETED. Everything is working fine, but while logging some messages I noticed that after I kill the application it starts up again anywhere from immediately to a minute later.

The only receiver that could be starting the service is registered to BOOT_COMPLETED. So my question is why is my application starting up on it's own after the phone has **already** booted up.

From the Android Site:

> Broadcast Action: This is broadcast once, after the system has finished booting. It can be used to perform application-specific initialization, such as installing alarms. You must hold the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in order to receive this broadcast.

To my understanding this event should only ever be broadcasting once so what else could be causing this event.

Edit: This is the code I am using in my BootReceiver (extends BroadCastReceiver) to start the service. This code is not duplicated **anywhere** else.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RandomToneService.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: How do you "kill the application"? What does `onStartCommand()` return in your `Service`?

Comment: I kill the application either by sliding it off screen, or using the Advanced Task Killer app

Comment: What does `onStartCommand()` return in your `Service`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm unfamiliar with that. To check should I override it and Log it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To check should I override it and Log it?

Not necessarily, but you need to read about [services and their lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle).

What you are doing by swiping away the app from the recent-tasks list is the same thing that Android would do when your process gets terminated due to low memory conditions. A `Service` can request to Android that it be automatically restarted in those cases, and that is done through the return value from `onStartCommand()`.

The default return value from `onStartCommand()` for a `Service` is `START_STICKY`, which tells Android to restart your service sometime later when there is memory. The default return value from `onStartCommand()` on an `IntentService` is either `START_NOT_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, depending upon whether or not you called `setIntentRedelivery()` and what you supplied there.

Hence, if you do *not* want your service to be automatically restarted in these conditions, you need to do something to get `onStartCommand()` to return `START_NOT_STICKY`, either:

- Call `setIntentRedelivery(false)` on your `IntentService`, or
- Override `onStartCommand()`, chaining to the superclass for default behavior, but then returning `START_NOT_STICKY`